# Regular expression to find unbroken text and insert space

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

I am building a forum and it is in beta right now. The users have begun to exploit certain things, like posting long strings of text with no spaces that will stretch the screen and ruin some styling. I just started using this code and it works fine.

```
        int charIndex = 0;
        int noSpaceCount = 0;
        foreach (char c in text.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (c != ' ')
                noSpaceCount++;
            else
                noSpaceCount = 0;

            if (noSpaceCount > 150)
            {
                text = text.Insert(charIndex, " ");
                noSpaceCount = 0;
            }
            charIndex++;
        }
```

This code works but I'd prefer a regular expression if possible. The problem is that I will be using regular expressions to identify links and I don't want to break long links with a space as those will be fixed by making the link display text abbreviated. So I don't want to insert a space into a piece of text that identifies as a URL, but I do want to insert a space every 150 characters of unbroken, non-link, text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be a very bad solution to fixing a layout problem. Can't you add word wrap?

Comment: Word wrap, or `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Word wrap only works on elements of a static size. It does not work on a div that is allowed to take up the width of the screen. It will just stretch that div to fit the contents.

Comment: How could a URL be identified? Would it start with `http(s)/ftp(s)://` or would it be wrapped in `[url=...]` or...?

Comment: Ideally it would start with http(s)/ftp(s):// or www.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was surprisingly complicated. Thank Eric and colleagues for the great .NET regex library.

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"(?<=     # Assert that the current position follows...
     \s        # a whitespace character
     |         # or
     ^         # the start of the string
     |         # or
     \G        # the end of the previous match.
    )          # End of lookbehind assertion
    (?!(?:ht|f)tps?://|www\.)  # Assert that we're not at the start of a URL.
    (\S{150})  # Match 150 characters, capture them.", 
    "$1 ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: Thank you! Testing it out now.

Comment: Woohoo! I have much respect for you regex gurus. I wish I could accept this answer twice.

Answer (score 0):

replace `"([^ ]{150})`" with `"\1 "` globally (modify according to your regex flavor)