# Word Wrapping with Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, word-wrap

EDIT FOR CLARITY - I know there are ways to do this in multiple steps, or using LINQ or vanilla C# string manipulation. The reason I am using a single regex call, is because I wanted practice with complex regex patterns. - END EDIT

I am trying to write a single regular expression that will perform word wrapping. It's extremely close to the desired output, but I can't quite get it to work.

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=^|\G)(.{1,20}(\s|$))", "$1\r\n", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

This is correctly wrapping words for lines that are too long, but it's adding a line break when there already is one.

Input

```
"This string is really long. There are a lot of words in it.\r\nHere's another line in the string that's also very long."
```

Expected Output

```
"This string is \r\nreally long. There \r\nare a lot of words \r\nin it.\r\nHere's another line \r\nin the string that's \r\nalso very long."
```

Actual Output

```
"This string is \r\nreally long. There \r\nare a lot of words \r\nin it.\r\n\r\nHere's another line \r\nin the string that's \r\nalso very long.\r\n"
```

Note the double "\r\n" between sentences where the input already had a line break and the extra "\r\n" that was put at the end.

Perhaps there's a way to conditionally apply different replacement patterns?
I.E. If the match ends in "\r\n", use replace pattern "$1", otherwise, use replace pattern "$1\r\n".

Here's a link to a similar question for wrapping a string with no white space that I used as a starting point.
[Regular expression to find unbroken text and insert space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749265/regular-expression-to-find-unbroken-text-and-insert-space)

Comment: so does your string really have the `\r\n` or those characters?

Comment: btw +1 for a clever way to wordwrap!

Comment: \r\n is the carriage return, then the new line escape characters. I'm testing this with a hard coded string, but the data this will run against is coming from a database and follows the same convention for line breaks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was quick-tested in Perl.

**Edit** - This regex code simulates the word wrap used (good or bad) in MS-Windows  *Notepad.exe*

```
 # MS-Windows  "Notepad.exe Word Wrap" simulation
 # ( N = 16 )
 # ============================
 # Find:     @"(?:((?>.{1,16}(?:(?<=[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?=\r?\n)|$|[^\S\r\n]))|.{1,16})(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n|$))"
 # Replace:  @"$1\r\n"
 # Flags:    Global     

 # Note - Through trial and error discovery, it apparears Notepad accepts an extra whitespace
 # (possibly in the N+1 position) to help alignment. This matters not because thier viewport hides it.
 # There is no trimming of any whitespace, so the wrapped buffer could be reconstituted by inserting/detecting a
 # wrap point code which is different than a linebreak.
 # This regex works on un-wrapped source, but could probably be adjusted to produce/work on wrapped buffer text.
 # To reconstitute the source all that is needed is to remove the wrap code which is probably just an extra "\r".

 (?:
      # -- Words/Characters 
      (                       # (1 start)
           (?>                     # Atomic Group - Match words with valid breaks
                .{1,16}                 #  1-N characters
                                        #  Followed by one of 4 prioritized, non-linebreak whitespace
                (?:                     #  break types:
                     (?<= [^\S\r\n] )        # 1. - Behind a non-linebreak whitespace
                     [^\S\r\n]?              #      ( optionally accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace )
                  |  (?= \r? \n )            # 2. - Ahead a linebreak
                  |  $                       # 3. - EOS
                  |  [^\S\r\n]               # 4. - Accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace
                )
           )                       # End atomic group
        |  
           .{1,16}                 # No valid word breaks, just break on the N'th character
      )                       # (1 end)
      (?: \r? \n )?           # Optional linebreak after Words/Characters
   |  
      # -- Or, Linebreak
      (?: \r? \n | $ )        # Stand alone linebreak or at EOS
 )
```

**Test Case**   The wrap width N is 16. Output matches Notepad's and over a variety of widths.

```
 $/ = undef;

 $string1 = <DATA>;

 $string1 =~ s/(?:((?>.{1,16}(?:(?<=[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?=\r?\n)|$|[^\S\r\n]))|.{1,16})(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n|$))/$1\r\n/g;

 print $string1;

 __DATA__
 hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbEDIT FOR CLARITY - I                    know there are  ways to do this in   multiple steps, or using LINQ or vanilla C#
 string manipulation. 

 The reason I am using a single regex call, is because I wanted practice. with complex
 regex patterns. - END EDIT
 pppppppppppppppppppUf
```

Output >>

```
 hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
 hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 EDIT FOR CLARITY 
 - I              
       know there 
 are  ways to do 
 this in   
 multiple steps, 
 or using LINQ or 
 vanilla C#
 string 
 manipulation. 

 The reason I am 
 using a single 
 regex call, is 
 because I wanted 
 practice. with 
 complex
 regex patterns. 
 - END EDIT
 pppppppppppppppp
 pppUf
```

Comment: When I first tried word wrapping with regex, I didn't think it was possible. This has definitely convinced me of the power of regex patterns.

Comment: Look at this one for process arguments. [Args](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303036/regular-expression-to-match-process-arguments/20303808#20303808). I highly recommend the http://RegexFormat.com application to process Regular Expressions.

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 5):

I would write an extension method like this.

```
var input = "This string is really long. There are a lot of words in it.\r\nHere's another line in the string that's also very long.";

var lines = input.SplitByLength(20).ToList();
```

---

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static  IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string input, int maxLen)
    {
        return Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1," + maxLen + @"})(?:\s|$)")
                    .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                    .Select(x => x.Trim());
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
This string is
really long. There
are a lot of words
in it.
Here's another line
in the string that's
also very long.
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @DanielA.White and other downvoters,  What is different then the output OP expects?

Comment: i think the problem is that you don't explain the regex solution.

Comment: Downvotes don't make sense. This solution is clearly better than the OP's actual approach.

Comment: @L.B he asked for A and you gave him A inside of B except A is different without an explanation.

Comment: @DanielA.White Even incorrect answers get less downvotes. I think this answer will be a good example for people voting without fully reading/understanding the question/answer.

Comment: This is a solution, yes. But I think this solution is pretty trivial. I'd bet all my 172 reputation points there's a reason why @Justin didn't do this in the first place.

Comment: @aj.toulan what kind of solution would you expect? It is a string operation, not a rocket science.

Comment: @L.B Not sure if I understand your analogy. It's possible that this code is processing millions strings per day. I would expect an answer with the same approach as the OP, just with a different pattern.

Comment: There may not be a satisfactory solution. If someone can explain why, this may be marked as a valid answer.

Comment: **a)** @aj.toulan And I don't understand your reasoning about *"It's possible that this code is processing millions strings per day"*. Would you really need that micro optimization? **b)** *If someone can explain why, this may be marked as a valid answer*: It works as OP wants.

Comment: @L.B a) possibly, I'm not the OP b) I was referring to the comment I made before that one, not your solution. c) No need to be rude. You're free to delete your answer whenever you please. If I find something that matches the OP's needs, I'll post it :D

Comment: @L.B My original solution was very similar to yours. I switched to the regex implementation for brevity as well as to learn more about regex.

Comment: I think this is a good solution and I imported it into my code. But I think that you should switch places on the `Where(...)` and the `Select(...)` as that will remove rows that become empty after `Trim(..)` call

Answer (score 2):

Add a place holder for the '\r\n' in the first pass, then replace any \r\n'placeholder' values with \r\n, finally make a third pass and replace the left over placeholders with \r\n.

For example using \u0000 as the placeholder

This of course only works if your original strings don't contain null

```
    string text = "This string is really long. There are a lot of words in it.\r\nHere's another line in the string that's also very long.";
    Console.WriteLine(text);

    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=^|\G)(.{1,20}(\s|$))", "$1\u0000", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    // break added after original
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "\r\n\u0000", "\r\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "\u0000", "\r\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't indicate what you want to have happen if a single word is longer than the number of characters to wordwrap, I chose to split at the maximum number of characters (20 in this case) if a word is longer than 20:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(.{1,19}\S)(?:\s+|$)|(.{20})", @"$1$2
", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

After the $1$2 there is a LF, not sure how it will show up here.  You may be able to insert \r\n there, but that somehow doesn't work on my emulator:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(.{1,19}\S)(?:\s+|$)|(.{20})", @"$1$2\r\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the possibility of a word being longer than the line width. I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that combines some of these good ideas.   I wrote a regex from scratch and found it is very similar to the one provided by sln, but it's a little shorter and probably does less backtracking:

```
# assuming a max line length of 16
(?:
    [^\r\n]{1,16}(?=\s|$)       # non-linebreaking characters followed by a space 
                                #    or end-of-string, up to the max line length
    |[^\r\n]{16}                # Or for really long words: a sequence of non-breaking  
                                #    characters exactly the line length
    |(?<=\n)\r?\n               # Or blank lines: a line break following another line break.  This works for \n or \r\n styles.
)
```

Like L.B I put the regex in a extension method, WordWrap:

```
void Main()
{
    var lineLen = 25;
    var test1 = "Some random words like calendar boat and breathe.\nAnd an extra line.\n\n\nAnd here's one that has to break in the middle because there are no spaces:\n"
        + String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, lineLen + 5).Select(i => (i % 10).ToString()));

    var test2 = test1.Replace("\n","\r\n");

    StringHelper.StringRuler(lineLen).Dump("ruler");
    String.Join("\n", test1.WordWrap(lineLen)).Dump("test 1");
    String.Join("\r\n", test2.WordWrap(lineLen)).Dump("test 2");
}

public static class StringHelper {

    public static IEnumerable<String> WordWrap(this string source, int lineLength) {
        return new Regex(
            @"(?:[^\r\n]{1,lineLength}(?=\s|$)|[^\r\n]{lineLength}|(?<=\n)\r?\n)"
                .Replace("lineLength", lineLength.ToString()))
            .Matches(source)
            .Cast<Match>()  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/7274451/555142
            .Select(m=>m.Value.Trim());
    }

    public static string StringRuler(int lineLength) {
        return 
            String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, lineLength)
                .Select(i => ((i % 10) == 0 ? (i / 10).ToString() : " "))) + "\n" 
            + String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, lineLength).Select(i => (i % 10).ToString())) + "\n" 
            + String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, lineLength).Select(i => "-")); 
    }

}
```

Testing with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) ([Instant Share](http://share.linqpad.net/koqxid.linq)).  There are two tests, the first for \n line breaks and the second for \r\n line breaks.

```
ruler

         1         2     
1234567890123456789012345
------------------------- 

test 1

Some random words like
calendar boat and
breathe.
And an extra line.


And here's one that has
to break in the middle
because there are no
spaces:
1234567890123456789012345
67890 


test 2

Some random words like
calendar boat and
breathe.
And an extra line.


And here's one that has
to break in the middle
because there are no
spaces:
1234567890123456789012345
67890
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in JS:

```
function wordWrap(s, width) {
  var r = '(?:(.{1,' + width + '})[ \\r\\t]+|(.{' + width + '}))(?!$)';
  r = new RegExp(r, 'g');
  // console.log(r);
  return s.replace(r, '$1$2\n');
}
```