# How is wordwrap in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am extracting data from XML using XSLT. I want to see data in xml-editor.How to wrap text to fit window in XSLT?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <wawes> 
            <xsl:for-each select="//VARIABLE">
                <xsl:sort select="@ID" order="descending"/>
                <wave>  
                    <id>  
                        <xsl:value-of select="@ID" ></xsl:value-of>    
                    </id>
                    <NAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
                    </NAME> 
                </wave>      
            </xsl:for-each>
        </wawes>          
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @rene most likely, but in some cases, not possible, which is what pulled me here this morning

Answer (score 1):

My other answer provides a solution using `XSLT-2`, whereas the initial scope of this question was `XSLT-1`.

This premise is based on the idea of repeatedly reiterating over the target string, slicing off variably sized, sub 50 segments and placing each one on its own line, and continuing this function until there is no more text available.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:user="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/user" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="user xs">
    <xsl:template name="user:FindLastSpace">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_string_length" select="string-length($text)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var4_result">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string(('0' = $var1_resultof_string_length)) != 'false'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="var2_resultof_substring" select="substring($text, $var1_resultof_string_length)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="var3_result">
                        <xsl:value-of select="($var2_resultof_substring = ' ')"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="($var2_resultof_substring = ',')"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="string(boolean(translate(normalize-space($var3_result), 'false0 ', ''))) != 'false'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var1_resultof_string_length"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="user:FindLastSpace">
                                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, '1', ($var1_resultof_string_length - '1'))"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="floor($var4_result)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="user:CrLf">
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="user:FormLines">
        <xsl:param name="remainingText" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="length" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_substring" select="substring($remainingText, '1', $length)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var2_resultof_FindLastSpace">
            <xsl:call-template name="user:FindLastSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$var1_resultof_substring"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var4_result">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string(($var2_resultof_FindLastSpace = '0')) != 'false'">
                    <xsl:variable name="var3_resultof_string_length" select="string-length($remainingText)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$var3_resultof_string_length"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="user:FindLastSpace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$var1_resultof_substring"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var5_resultof_CrLf">
            <xsl:call-template name="user:CrLf"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var6_resultof_FindLastSpace">
            <xsl:call-template name="user:FindLastSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$var1_resultof_substring"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var8_result">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string(($var6_resultof_FindLastSpace = '0')) != 'false'">
                    <xsl:variable name="var7_resultof_string_length" select="string-length($remainingText)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$var7_resultof_string_length"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="user:FindLastSpace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$var1_resultof_substring"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var11_result">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string((substring($remainingText, ($var8_result + '1')) = '')) != 'false'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="var9_resultof_FindLastSpace">
                        <xsl:call-template name="user:FindLastSpace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$var1_resultof_substring"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="var10_result">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="string(($var9_resultof_FindLastSpace = '0')) != 'false'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="string-length($remainingText)"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:call-template name="user:FindLastSpace">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$var1_resultof_substring"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:call-template name="user:FormLines">
                        <xsl:with-param name="remainingText" select="substring($remainingText, ($var10_result + '1'))"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(concat(substring($remainingText, '1', $var4_result), $var5_resultof_CrLf), $var11_result)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xformResult>
            <xsl:call-template name="user:FormLines">
                <xsl:with-param name="remainingText" select="'Google HQ, 345 Spear St, San Francisco, Foo, Bar, Baz, 012310123'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="length" select="floor('50')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xformResult>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Works perfectly in many tests. Please forgive its craziness, I threw it together in MapForce

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping text in order to fit the screen size or resolution is usually not related to XSLT. XSLT is only concerned with transforming XML, not with the presentation and layout of XML data.

And if you think about it that's not too bad: the same XML must be equally accessible to all types of screen sizes, resolutions - and all types of applications, including XML editors. It would be presumptuous to fit XML to your unique combination of these three factors (what about window size?).

Instead, as pointed out by @rene, wrapping text comes as a feature with virtually every text editor. For example, there is <kbd>CTRL + W</kbd> for this in UltraEdit.

N.b. it is not technically impossible to enforce wrapping text in XSLT. You can introduce newline characters in the text content of your elements. But

- Their rendering depends on your application. An XML editor is likely *not* to render them at all.
- It's still unclear *where* exactly they should be introduced, given that at "transform time" you have no way of knowing what screens, windows and applications are going to access the XML data

Comment: @michael.hor257k this question is tagged xml and xslt, text editors are not available ;)

Comment: @topherg Did it occur to you that this answer was not written by michael? Besides, he has raised a valid objection whereas you are obviously only trying to be funny.

Comment: yes, it did, I was not trying to be funny, I was pointing out the fact that your answer was equally as floored, if not more so by the fact that you didn't even stay within the context area, whereas I varied on the subversion. you're answer was not helpful, and prompted me to answer to help others who might be having the same problem

Comment: @topherg So, you would like to continue to claim that text editors are not available to a programmer? If my answer does not answer what was asked, please point out to me where I strayed from the topic.

Comment: I have had this problem regularly, and I never have text editors available to me while its in production. Why would you ask how to do it in xslt when there are so many easier ways?

Comment: Now I am sitting, I can give you an accurate example: We process documents that come in from clients in order for those documents to be valid to the next system. They have their own address format, and the next system has its own too. We generally get bulks of 10-15000 addresses in a file, and that has to be processed in a few seconds. With the system we use, we are limited to XSLT whereas I would prefer Java, but either way, it would be impossible to achieve with a Text Editor. With that experience, seeing such a question about XSLT only, that would discount any manual intervention

Comment: @topherg In my opinion you misunderstood the OP's level of knowledge and intent. As I see it, the OP assumes that text wrapping is a task that is usually performed by XSLT to display XML data, to "fit the window". There is no use bringing in your entirely separate problem of transforming 15k items and only display a certain amount of characters on one line.

Comment: @topherg Secondly, you misunderstood my answer. I am not proposing to change the XML data in any way with a text editor. I am saying that most text editors have ways to make it _look as if_ there was a text wrap in the XML file. In general, you should not mix data with presentation - which is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: My apologies, I appear to have gone off at a complete tangent... and completely skipped over the words `xml-editor` as anything other than a program and more as a transformative property that would be displayed. I can see that you saw that, and entirely focused on it being a presentation issue, rather than a data formation issue. Soz bud

Answer (score -1):

I have had reasonable success using Regular Expressions to break up a string using `XSLT-2`'s `replace` function (replacing with `$1\n`). I know you are concerned with `XSLT-1`, but from what I have found, regular expressions are the only way to do this without iterative parsing.

Initially, I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431801/word-wrapping-with-regular-expressions/20434776#20434776), but I couldn't get it to work within the Regular Expressions subset allowed with XSLTs, mainly hobbled by the lack of positive lookahead.

Although XSLT is about XML manipulation, my line of work has proven that that is not the only use case as we use XSLT to perform mass data transformations for system and client interoperability, not only on XML data, but plaintext and formatted text (i.e. CSV) data as well.

One such transformation required the implosion of a set of address elements:

```
<Address>
    <Name>Google HQ</Name>
    <Line1>345 Spear St</Line1>
    <Line2></Line2>
    <Line3></Line3>
    <Line4></Line4>
    <City>San Francisco</City>
    <PostCode>94105</PostCode>
    <County>CA</County>
    <Country>United States</Country>
    <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
</Address>
```

into a text block that would resemble:

```
Google HQ,
345 Spear St,
San Francisco,
94105,
CA,
USA
```

however, the field that this information would be put into was limited to only 4 lines, and each line being 50 characters. To conserve space, I put the `PostCode`, `County`, and `CountryCode` on a single line and appended it separately, so I had 3 lines of 50 characters instead. I then took the remaining fields, and CSV'd them together (unless one was blank), such that it looked like:

> Google HQ, 345 Spear St, San Francisco

Looking at the question and answer I linked to above, I got the regular expression (swapped 16 for 50 in the lengths):

```
(?:((?>.{1,50}(?:(?<=[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?=\r?\n)|$|[^\S\r\n]))|.{1,50})(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n|$))
```

however, it would not work in XSLT.

For starters, it didn't recognise `(?>` (atomic groups), or `(?=` (positive lookaheads, but after swapping them with anonymous groups, it worked.

But after that, I got errors about it matching a zero-length string. That was being caused by the last occurrences of `|$`, which was causing it to match to the end of line, but without that, it finally worked. It was not as neat as I had hoped, but it did compress the single line of text into a set of lines that were narrower than 50 characters at each point. The final regular expression was:

```
(?:((?:.{1,50}(?:(?:[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?:\r?\n)|$|[^\S\r\n]))|.{1,50})(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n))
```

Now, in my case which doesn't apply to you, I had a line restriction too, but I just discarded the remaining lines.

Hope that's of some help to you

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 1.0; regex is not available.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, it says so, but it is a solution if he will change, and provides assistance to others who are led here. this is where google took me, and gave me nothing else. i am putting together an xslt 1 answer