# Wrap the long lines in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, word-wrap

Wrap the long lines in the given text to the given length. Example:
  
    `'To be or not to be-that is the question', 5 =>
    To be
    or
    not
    to be
    -that
    is
    the
    quest
    ion`

Comment: Generally it would be better to phrase this as a question and not as a command. Perhaps "I'm trying to take a long one lined string and convert it into a multi line string where no line is longer than a given length. What is the best way to go about this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
 # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431801/word-wrapping-with-regular-expressions/20434776#20434776

 # MS-Windows  "Notepad.exe Word Wrap" simulation
 # ( N = 16 )
 # ------------------
 # Trims optional non-linebreak whitespace
 # external to the viewport
 # ============================
 # Find:     @"(?:(?:(?>(.{1,16})(?:(?<=[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?<=[,.;:!/?])|(?=\r?\n|[-#%&*@_])|[^\S\r\n]))|(.{1,16}))(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n))"
 # Replace:  @"$1$2\r\n"
 # Flags:    Global
```

https://regex101.com/r/E7FxHg/1

```
 # Note - Through trial and error discovery, it apparears Notepad accepts an extra whitespace
 # (possibly in the N+1 position) to help alignment. This matters not because thier viewport hides it.
 # There is no trimming of any whitespace, so the wrapped buffer could be reconstituted by inserting/detecting a
 # wrap point code which is different than a linebreak.
 # This regex works on un-wrapped source, but could probably be adjusted to produce/work on wrapped buffer text.
 # To reconstitute the source all that is needed is to remove the wrap code which is probably just an extra "\r".

 (?:
      # -- Words/Characters 
      (?:
           (?>                     # Atomic Group - Match words with valid breaks
                ( .{1,16} )             # (1), 1-N characters
                                        #  Followed by one of 4 prioritized, non-linebreak whitespace
                (?:                     #  break types:
                     (?<= [^\S\r\n] )        # 1. - Behind a non-linebreak whitespace
                     [^\S\r\n]?              #      ( optionally accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace )
                  |  (?<= [,.;:!/?] )        # 2. - Behind sepcial punctuation breaks
                  |  (?=                     # 3. - Ahead a linebreak or special punctuation breaks
                          \r? \n 
                       |  [-#%&*@_] 
                     )
                  |  [^\S\r\n]               # 4. - Accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace
                )
           )                       # End atomic group
        |  
           ( .{1,16} )             # (2), No valid word breaks, just break on the N'th character
      )
      (?: \r? \n )?           # Optional linebreak after Words/Characters
   |  
      # -- Or, Linebreak
      (?: \r? \n )            # Stand alone linebreak
 )
```

Comment: thanks, I tried to solve this way, but the whole problem in the dash

Comment: you are now my hero. Thank you!

Comment: @DanilPan'shin - You're welcome. I added the punctuation word-break bias for before and after to flesh it out. I'm using this one.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```
max_length = 5

result = ""
word_array = 'To be or not to be-that is the question'.split(/\s|-/)
line = word_array.shift
word_array.each do |word|
  if (line + " " + word).length <= max_length
    line << " " + word
  elsif word.length > max_length
    result << line + "\n" unless line.empty?
    line = ""
    word.each_char do |c|
      line << c
      if line.length == max_length
        result << line + "\n"
        line = ""
      end
    end
  else
    result << line + "\n"
    line = word
  end
end
result << line
puts result
```

Comment: Thanks, but problem is here: 
```to be
-that
is```
The problem is in the dash, and your solution is missing.

how to make a dash stay?
Thanks.