# Given a string insert a new newline character at 50th position and exclude whole words

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new line"
String parsedStr = str.replace("(.{50})","$1\n");
```

I need the string new string to be

```
Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new 
line
```

But I get like this

```
 Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new l
 ine
```

I came across word boundary(\b). Tried but does not work with my case.

Comment: Seems like you want the first space after the first 49 characters?

Comment: Also `str.replaceFirst("(.{49})","$1" + System.lineSeparator())`. `replace` didn't work for me

Comment: I think there is a link somewhere on how to do word wrap. Think I posted a few somewhere. But, _word wrap_ is what you're trying to do..

Comment: Can you confirm exactly what you're trying to do and what you mean by *`\b` does not work with your case*? I'm getting correct result with replace on [`^(.{0,50}\b)` replace with `$1\n`](https://regex101.com/r/7GiCzu/1)

Comment: @ctwheels I'm not the asker, but if you use \b then line 2 might start with a period.

Comment: ctwheels is right, it can be enhanced as `.replaceAll("(?Us).{1,50}\\b\\p{Punct}*+(?!$)", "$0\n")`. Just punctuation won't count to the 50 char limit then.

Comment: @PatrickParker you could use [`^(.{0,50}\b(?!\p{P}|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/0baybx/1) for that case.

Comment: You should definitely note that any sort of html tags, bbml or anything similar will cause severe issues in wrapping. Some Markdown (like this site uses, Reddit uses similar) will too (links, images).

Comment: Possible duplicate of _[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431801/word-wrapping-with-regular-expressions/20434776#20434776)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may very well be a simple solution to your problem. Seeing as how the OP has only provided us one sample string, it's uncertain if there are any *special cases*, but the following works for their sample string.

**Note:** I am posting the *raw* regex. You will need to escape all necessary characters (backslashes) in Java.

#### Option 1

You might even be able to use `^(.{0,50})` (there's a space at the end) instead of `\b`.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7GiCzu/1)

```
^(.{0,50}\b)
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(.{0,50}\b)` Capture any character up to 50 times asserting the end position matches a word boundary `\b` into capture group 1

Replacement: `$1\n`

Result:

```
Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new 
line
```

#### Option 2

This method uses Option 1 as a base but adds logic for a string that may add `\n` before punctuation (which *may* be the unintended result). For those cases, you may use the following.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7GiCzu/2)

```
^(.{0,50}\b(?!\p{P}|$))
```

- Same logic as Option 1, but ensures `\b` doesn't match `\p{p}` (a punctuation character) or the end of the string.

Result (the second option would have `\n` before `.` using Option 1's regex):

```
Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new 
line
This line contains 50 characters to show dot 
issue.Some other string here
```

Answer (score 2):

Construct the regex clause `.{1,N}` with the number of characters to use per line.
Like for  50, it would be `.{1,50}`.

Compressed

Find: `(?:(?:(?>(.{1,50})(?:(?<=[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?<=[,.;:!/?])[^\S\r\n]?|(?=\r?\n|[-#%&*@_])|[^\S\r\n]))|(.{1,50}))(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n))`

Replace: `$1$2\r\n`

Readable

```
 (?:
      # -- Words/Characters 
      (?:
           (?>                           # Atomic Group - Match words with valid breaks
                ( .{1,50} )                   # (1), 1-N characters
                                              #  Followed by one of 4 prioritized, non-linebreak whitespace
                (?:                           #  break types:
                     (?<= [^\S\r\n] )              # 1. - Behind a non-linebreak whitespace
                     [^\S\r\n]?                    #      ( optionally accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace )
                  |  (?<= [,.;:!/?] )              # 2. - Behind sepcial punctuation breaks
                     [^\S\r\n]?                    #      ( optionally accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace )
                  |  (?=                           # 3. - Ahead a linebreak or special punctuation breaks
                          \r? \n 
                       |  [-#%&*@_] 
                     )
                  |  [^\S\r\n]                     # 4. - Accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace
                )
           )                             # End atomic group
        |  
           ( .{1,50} )                   # (2), No valid word breaks, just break on the N'th character
      )
      (?: \r? \n )?                 # Optional linebreak after Words/Characters
   |  
      # -- Or, Linebreak
      (?: \r? \n )                  # Stand alone linebreak
 )
```

Comment: Wow, with a regex like that it seems much clearer to just start looking for white space after position 50, with a plain old loop, without any regex.

Comment: I got Line 2 starting with a space character with this input "Hello how are you today music fine. This is a new. line". You probably want to split after the space or erase it by matching it outside of the matching groups.

Comment: @PatrickParker - The behind special punctuation was a new addition. Forgot to add the consume optional extra space after it. Fixed, and thanks.

Comment: @sln it's still behaving inconsistently. the space is consumed with my example input but not consumed with OP's original input. also why not consume multiple whitespaces at EOL?

Comment: @PatrickParker - Word wrap doesn't know anything about the body `.{1,N}` of text. Sure, you could do a `[^\S\r\n]*` after every valid break, but it won't do anything to the _body_. So you will still get lines like `text <20 spaces or tabs>more text<break>` if it happens to fall within range _N_. This word wrap above, identically emulates that in _MS Notepad_ with the addition of punctuation breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String str = "Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new line"
int index = 50;
while(str.getCharAt(index) != ' ') 
{
    index--;
}

String parsedStr = str.replace("(.{index})","$1\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

This does *literally* what you asked for, and nothing more. However, if you really want to implement word-wrapping, then it's not a great approach.

```
String str = "Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new line";
String parsedStr = str.replaceFirst("^(.*?)\\s*((\\S(?!\\s))*(?<=.{50}).*$)",
        "$1"+System.lineSeparator()+"$2");
String [] pieces = parsedStr.split(System.lineSeparator());
for(String piece : pieces ) {
    System.out.format("length %2d: \"%s\"%n", piece.length(), piece);
}
```

**Output:**

> length 48: "Hello how are you today music fine.This is a new"
>
> length   4: "line"

**Explanation:**

- `^          =` beginning of line (begin group 1)
- `.*?        =` reluctantly match any number of characters (end group 1)
- `\s*        =` consume all whitespace where the line will split (begin group 2)
- `\S*        =` match any number of non-whitespace characters...
- `(?!\\s)    =` NOT followed by whitespace, otherwise we'd miss a split chance at exactly 50
- `(?<=.{50}) =` positive look-behind of exactly 50 characters
- `.*$        =` include all remaining characters in the line (end group 2)

---

**A simpler option:**

You could get very similar results with this far simpler regex:

```
String parsedStr = str.replaceFirst("^(.{0,50})\\s+",
        "$1"+System.lineSeparator());
```

*(credits to [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) for similar suggestion)*

The only difference is that this one could end up with some extra whitespace at the end on Line 1 if there were multiple spaces prior to the split. But that's not a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks it works.  Can you please explain what   
 does this mean `"^(.*?)(\\S*(?<=.{50}).*$)` `"$1"+System.lineSeparator()+"$2"`

Comment: @Arun [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is what to do when someone answers your question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark ✔ beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. There is no need to add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".

Comment: @Arun note: I have fixed my regex to handle a split chance at exactly 50. Please accept one of the correct answers which you found most helpful.