# How to do text wrapping without adding newline if the residue is short?

Tags: regex, replace, word-wrap

## Description

Say I have a lot of strings, some of them are very long:

```
Aim for the moon. If you miss, you may hit a star. – Clement Stone
Nothing about us without us
```

I want to have a text wrapper doing this algorithm:

1. Starting from the beginning of the string, identify the nearest blank character ( ) that around position 25
2. **If the residue is smaller than 5 character-length, then do nothing. If not, replace that blank character with `\n`**
3. Identify the next nearest blank character in the end of the next 25 characters
4. Return to 2 until end of line

So that text will be replaced to:

```
Aim for the moon. If you\nmiss, you may hit a star.\n– Clement Stone
Nothing about us without us
```

## Attempt 1

Consulting [Wrapping Text With Regular Expressions](https://macromates.com/blog/2006/wrapping-text-with-regular-expressions/)

- Matching pattern: `(.{1,25})( +|$\n?)`
- Replacing pattern: `$1\n`

But this will produce `Nothing about us without\nus`, which is not preferable.

## Attempt 2

Using a [Lookahead Construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in a [If-Then-Else Conditionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html):

- Matching pattern: `(.{1,25})(?(?=(.{1,5}$).*))( +|$\n?)`
- Replacing pattern: `$1$2\n`

It still produce `Nothing about us without\nus`, which is not preferable.

Comment: The string length is known, 25 from the left or 25 from the right after you reverse the string. Regex will only help you when it searches left to right. Reverse a string, search right, reverse it again, search right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your input is run line-by-line, and there is no newline character in the middle of a line, then you can try this:

- Pattern: `(.{1,25}.{1,5}$|.{1,25}(?= ))`
- Substitution: `$1\n`

Then apply this:

- Pattern: `\n`
- Substitution: `\n`

Comment: This does not work for the sample output provided in the original question.

Comment: yes it does not work as desired, but it's an acceptable solution until I can make it work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Created this based on @sln 's? [answer to a different word wrap problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434776/406712).

All I have added is this alternative point to add a line break:

"Expand by up to 5 characters until before a linebreak or EOS"

and changed the number of characters allowed from `50` to `25`

```
[^\r\n]{1,5}(?=\r?\n|$)
```

### Compressed

```
(?:((?>.{1,25}(?:[^\r\n]{1,5}(?=\r?\n|$)|(?<=[^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]?|(?=\r?\n)|$|[^\S\r\n]))|.{1,25})(?:\r?\n)?|(?:\r?\n|$))
```

### Replacement

`$1` followed by a linebreak

```
$1\r\n
```

### Preview

https://regex101.com/r/pRqdhi/1

### Detailed Regular Expression

```
(?:
      # -- Words/Characters 
      (                       # (1 start)
           (?>                     # Atomic Group - Match words with valid breaks
                .{1,25}                 #  1-N characters
                                        #  Followed by one of 4 prioritized, non-linebreak whitespace
                (?:                     #  break types:
                     [^\r\n]{1,5}(?=\r?\n|$) # Expand by up to 5 characters until before a linebreak or EOS
                  |
                     (?<= [^\S\r\n] )        # 1. - Behind a non-linebreak whitespace
                     [^\S\r\n]?              #      ( optionally accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace )
                  |  (?= \r? \n )            # 2. - Ahead a linebreak
                  |  $                       # 3. - EOS
                  |  [^\S\r\n]               # 4. - Accept an extra non-linebreak whitespace
                )
           )                       # End atomic group
        |  
           .{1,25}                 # No valid word breaks, just break on the N'th character
      )                       # (1 end)
      (?: \r? \n )?           # Optional linebreak after Words/Characters
   |  
      # -- Or, Linebreak
      (?: \r? \n | $ )        # Stand alone linebreak or at EOS
 )
```

Comment: why do we need to have the non-capturing group at the beginning of the string? It seems to do nothing

Comment: Nope the outer non-capturing group is not absolutely required. Personally, I commonly add outer non-capturing groups as an indicator of a later [alteration](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in complex regular expressions for readability.

Comment: do you mean that if you add an `|` at the end of the regex later, you can do that quicker?